# Is it possible for Azure API Management to synchronously post to Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-api-management, azure-servicebus-queues

I am converting a monolithic application to microservices.  I have set up an API Management layer and a Service Bus all within a Service Fabric.  The idea is to use messages to communicate to the microservices so they do not know about eachother.

When one microservice needs information it posts a message to the service bus and it gets fulfilled and a reply is sent and correlated.

The only problem is that the API Management posts the message to the service bus and returns without waiting for a reply therefore the client does not get a response.

Is there a way to have the API Management wait for a reply?

Would this need a sort of broker service in-between?

Is it better to just have a REST layer on each microservice that the API Management could call but then the services would use the service bus?

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE:**

I think the only way to have Api Management wait is use of a logic app.  Not sure about this.

Any Azure experts out there?

Comment: I think that this sentence is incorrect "The only problem is that the API Management posts the message to the service bus and returns without waiting for a reply therefore the client does not get a response."

because API Management will wait 300 seconds by default for a response and if it does not then it drops the call.

you might have a case where Service Bus receives a message and returns a repose  with 200 status code and and then process the message and provide the results somewhere else. is that the case?

Comment: Thanks Mohammad.  The service bus exposes an url that posts a message to the queue and then returns.  So APIM thinks everything is good and returns what the service bus returns as it is just forwarding the request.  I need some in-between logic that waits for a response and returns that but i don't know how to have APIM call a function.Sounds like I should just write a microservice that does this and have all the endpoints on APIM call this.

Answer (score 2):

The way APIM is behaving is actually expected.

Service Bus is meant to decouple different (micro)services and inherently doesn't have a request-response style of operation though it can be implemented that way.

Here is one way to can design/implement you system

- First, for a request-response style operation with Service Bus, one way you can achieve it is by using **two queues**.

  One for sending the request (along with some Unique ID - GUID will do) and the other for receiving the response (which again contains the Unique ID sent in the request).
- Instead of having APIM work with Service Bus, call a Logic App or Function which does this for you.
- Finally, waiting for the response is something that will depend on your use case.

  If you have a very long running task, its best to follow the Async Pattern implemented by both [Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres#use-the-http-request-trigger) and Functions ([using Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-concepts#async-http)), which return a `202 Accepted` response immediately with a status URI that your client can poll for updates.

  But if its a quick response (before the HTTP request times out), you could probably wait for the response service bus message and return the response then. For this, your Logic App or Function would have to poll/wait for the service bus message with the same unique ID and then return the response.

Comment: Thank you Thank you for a response! So the "Instead of having APIM work with Service Bus, call a Logic App or Function which does this for you" is exactly what I am trying to do.  Do you have any example or info of how to do this with a logic app or function?  All I want to do is have APIM call a function and i'll handle the rest (posting and waiting for response message from bus).  I am a noob to azure but learning and could use some info on how to do this.  Thanks.

Comment: Adding a [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-function-app-as-api) or [logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-logic-app-as-api) into APIM is documented and can be achieved through the portal itself.

Comment: I have the same problem and the only solution I can see to be able to get request/reply from servicebus is to have the API management call a function app that acts as a proxy which publishes the message to the servicebus queue with a session id and waits to receive a message with that session id on another queue. Finally it will return the Rest API call as reponse to API management which can then finally send back the response to the API client. Let me know if some other method of achieving request/reply is possible with azure servicebus.